# Identity Platform Sign In - using OpenID connect provider with Code Flow

Tags: firebase, openid-connect, google-identity

We are trying to Sign In the user using OpenID Connect provider - using Code Flow (works fine with implict flow). Issue we are experiencing is that our OIDC provider requires `private_key_jwt` auth metod to be used.

Only option on Identity Platform when we create custom OpenID Connect provider is Client Secret. I assume we would need to pass Private Key (as with Apple Provider) instead of Client Secret for this to work? Is that even possible with Identity Platform?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, In Identity Platform [Authentication Using OpenID Connect with Apple](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/openid-connect) is not possible with Private Key for that You have to **Generate Client Secret**.

The reason why we need to create Client secret(for Apple Provider) is mentioned [here](https://martin-robert-fink.medium.com/generating-apple-client-secret-with-dart-28f29a55f8f0) in the Article as :

> Apple’s support for OAuth2 has a number of differences compared to all
> the other social providers. Most providers (Google, Github, Facebook)
> generate the client_id and client_secret for you. You just need to
> keep them in a secure place on the server. In the Apple process, you
> first download a private key, and then generate a client_secret using
> that private key. The other difference with Apple is that they don’t
> support using localhost as a redirect. In the end, I initiate the
> OAuth2 process on the Flutter client; but all the redirects and the
> token exchange process happen on the server.

In order to generate the client secret, You can follow the steps mentioned in the [Article](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple#generate-the-client-secret).

For more  information, you can refer to the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65512845/15774176) on how to generate client secrets on  Apple Platform.

Comment: @igpe Posted an answer, is it helpful?

Comment: Divyani Yadav, thank you for the answer. We are not using Apple Provider. We are using custom OIDC provider with IDP, that uses private key to create client_assertion (jwt token signed with private key), which based on the articles that you have provided is very similar to secret_key required by apple provider. That helped to better understand the issue, but since secret_key is a static value (set when setting up oidc provider on IDP) it might not work in case with our identity provider.